# input não está puxando valor certo do banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, input

Preciso de uma ajuda.

Em meu sistema, eu tenho um input que trás uma data do banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver na foto acima a data informada está `06/09/2017 00:00`, só que a real data deste campo é `05/09/2017 22:03`.

O formato que esta no meu banco está assim `2017-09-05 22:03:03.757` e logo abaixo está o meu input que puxa está data.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align: center;" value="@(Model.DataRandomizacao?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") ?? "Não randomizado")" disabled>
```

alguém poderia me ajudar?

eu consegui resolver desta forma.

```
 @{ DateTime RandomizacaoData = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.Randomizacao.RandomizacaoData); }
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-left:0; text-align: center;" value="@RandomizacaoData.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")" disabled>
```

só que preciso que caso não haja uma data ele apareça **"Não Randomizado"** como o exemplo antigo.

Comment: Qual o valor do DataRandomizacao sem  o ToString()?

Comment: Sem o ToString da erro e não consigo visualizar a data

Comment: Coloca o breakpoint nessa linha do seu cshtml -> CTRL+ALT+I para abrir o intermediate windows -> digite seu Model.DataRandomizacao.

Comment: o breakPoint não funciona nesta linha da data

Comment: Você esta em modo debug? Vai na sua Controller, onde possui a Action que chama essa View e veja o Model que você retorna para a View.

Comment: A variavel DataRandomização vem deste model @model Basics.Domain.Entities.ViewModel.Detalhes dentro deste model está a variavel public DateTime? DataRandomizacao { get; set; }

Comment: @GabrielColetta Eu consegui resolver de uma outra maneira, só que estou com um outro problema, caso não haja uma data, ele aparece "Não randomizado" vou editar o codigo e mostrar como fiz

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver pessoal. 
Obrigado a quem ajudou.

```
@if (Model.DataRandomizacao == null)
{
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#569CD0; color:#ffffff">Data da randomização:</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-left:0; text-align: center;" value="Não Randomizado" disabled>
}
else
{
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#569CD0; color:#ffffff">Data da randomização:</span>
    DateTime RandomizacaoData = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.Randomizacao.RandomizacaoData);
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-left:0; text-align: center;" value="@RandomizacaoData.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")" disabled>
}
```